# Trying to use javascript/JQuery on a Tumblr blog to retrieve a perma-link URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to retrieve the permalink URL from within the HTML:

```
<div id="article-holder">
<article class="photo 1288393" 
data-permalink="http://skinsocial.tumblr.com/post/123888396043/if-you-were-given">
    </article>
    </div>
```

My attempts are:

```
article-holder.querySelectorAll('data-permalink');
```

and

```
$('#article-holder').find('data-permalink');
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I think you are missing quote after class. `<article class="photo 1288393" data-permalink="http://...iven"></article>`

Comment: *"Trying to use querySelectorAll..."* Why, if you're already using jQuery?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Fixed thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm learning thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#article-holder article').attr('data-permalink');
```

Comment: Note that `data` is probably overkill for this: It will grab **all** the `data-*` attributes and cache them in jQuery's data cache for the element, creating multiple objects in the process, and keep all that until the element is removed. To just access a single `data-*` attribute, `attr` is the correct tool.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you TJ, that was very helpful information. Answer updated.